# Is CoInitialize(NULL) call expensive after CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED) on the same thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, com

I have code that is calling `CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED)` on a thread and later calling `CoInitialize(NULL)` on the same thread.

I know that the `CoInitialize(NULL)` call will fail with    `RPC_E_CHANGED_MODE`, but that is not my concern here. This error is properly handled by the code as follows:-

```
if (retValue == RPC_E_CHANGED_MODE) {
    thModel = kThModelMulti;  // thread was initialized with MTA model
}
```

Please do not worry about the functional aspect.
**Is there any performance issue with the call to `CoInitialize(NULL)`  - would this be expensive ? If so, I shall change the code to figure out to not even call`CoInitialize(NULL)` if `CoInitializeEx` has already been called.**

Comment: @Dan, thanks for editing it.

Comment: It will always fail.  Quickly.  Calling such a very important function randomly is a massively bad idea.  What you have to fear is that it will succeed.  You are not taking care of the promise you made.

Comment: Please don't change your question into something that no longer even remotely resembles the question that was live, when the answer was published. Besides, we don't know what *"expensive"* is to you, or why you are calling a function that can fail, when you apparently can identify ahead of time, that it will.

Comment: there are sometime limitations in the code because of which you can't know ahead of time.
With *"expensive"*, I mean is the time taken equivalent to CoInitializeEx (in this scenario).

Comment: @IInspectable: btw, downvoting the question wasn't a fair thing to do in my opinion.

Comment: Not sure why you are telling me. I have no opinion on whether this is fair or not. If you are looking for a reason, why this question earned a down-vote, you're going to have to wait for the user who did for feedback. As for the technicalities: You explained, that you can know ahead of time, always, whether the call will fail or not. It's right there, in your question.

Comment: ok thanks. I meant I would have to remove that current limitation to know ahead of time. 

However, ignoring the functional aspect, can you please tell me your thoughts on the performance aspect of it.

Comment: will appreciate the feedback from the users who are down-voting my question.

Comment: can someone please tell me the thoughts on the performance aspect of it (leaving other issues behind).

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do, but you are trying to fix a symptom, not the real problem. COM doesn't have a way to ask if CoInitialize has been already called because *you're not supposed to need to know*. Code that calls CoInitialize *must* own the thread. If a piece of code doesn't know whether/which CoInitialize has already been called, that code invariable doesn't own the thread and has no business calling CoInitialize. Every time I've seen code like this there has been an underlying broken architecture. Think higher level, and/or please post what you're actually doing.

Comment: The question on the performance characteristics isn't answerable. There is no official documentation that makes any guarantees, and an answer that's correct today may no longer be tomorrow. Or on another OS. Or in another environment. A failed call is *probably* not very costly, but you should seriously consider fixing the underlying issue, instead of working around it.

Comment: thanks everyone for your inputs.

Answer (score 2):

Calling [`CoInitialize(NULL)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms678543.aspx) has the same effect as calling [`CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms695279.aspx). If you are calling `CoInitialize(NULL)` on a thread that has already called `CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED)`, it will fail with error code `RPC_E_CHANGED_MODE`. This is specifically called out in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms678543.aspx):

> After the concurrency model for a thread is set, it cannot be changed. A call to **CoInitialize** on an apartment that was previously initialized as multithreaded will fail and return RPC_E_CHANGED_MODE.

The performance implications do not matter. This is a functional issue, aka bug.

Comment: I edited my question to address what you said. Thanks !

Comment: @RakeshAgarwal: If your code calls `CoInitialize(NULL)` it does so, because the calling thread implements STA-specific synchronization. There is no way to properly handle the case, where this fails, because the calling thread is already in the MTA.

Comment: At this place in the code, it wants to know the thread model but it doesn't know whether CoInitializeEx(...) has already been called. So, it calls `CoInitialize(NULL)` and based on the return value, understands the thread model.

Comment: @RakeshAgarwal: Calling `CoInitialize(NULL)` cannot verify, whether `CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED)` has previously been called. If you meant to write `COINIT_MULTITHREADED` instead, that's still a bad idea: Changing state as a way to query state. If you need to keep track about thread state yourself, and don't know where to store this data, use the [TLS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686749.aspx) instead.